# Differecnce between app:installDebug vs adb install

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

whats difference between app:installDebug vs ADB install command.
I observer **adb install** takes less time to install apk compare to app:installDebug

Answer (score 1):

`adb install` simply installs APK file of a given path.

On the other hand, `app:installDebug` Gradle task **builds** the app using `app:assembleDebug`, then install it.

`app:installDebug` installs the app using `adb install …` :)